# How to fix 504 gateway timeout error in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# Excel addin. I am sending 1000 rows of data to server with 5 threads with 200 http requests per thread.

After first 4-5 http requests, I get **504 gateway timeout** error.
However, when I see at the backend, all the http requests are being processed properly.

From the web, I only understood that 504 error is mostly fixed at the server side.
But before contacting server admin, I want to explore more on this kind of error?

Did anybody face same issue before?

Below is the way I managed to handle requests with multi-treading:

```
int threadCount = 5;
Thread[] threadPool = new Thread[threadCount ];
List<string> data = GetDataFromExcel(); //1000 rows of data
List<string> dataPartition = CreatePartion(threadCount ) // 200 objects/rows per thread
for(List<string> partition: dataPartition)
{
threadPool[thread_index] = new Thread(() =>
//Handling requests code
);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything is correct on your side, there is no reason to explore any further your code if you are not willing to do things slowly, by for example spacing up the time between each request.

All the codes on the range 500 (500, 503 or 504) - references [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) - directly identifies that the problem is indeed on the server side. As you can probably tell, you have a lot of data transferring at the same time and it's likely a bandwidth situation on the server.